# Android Text Placement

Tags: android, android-layout

I am relatively new to Android development, and am developing an application with an image for a background. I need the ability to have text reliably and precisely placed in relation to certain points on the background image. I developed the application debugging on a Droid Charge. Everything looks fine there. However, I downloaded the application to a Droid X, and the text is a little off. I imagine I am missing some fundamental understanding about Android development, and would appreciate any help. Also, I believe this person is having a similar problem.

[Screen sizes and precise element placement on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534337/screen-sizes-and-precise-element-placement-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to understand that due to support of multiple screen, it's not wise to have a certain points or coordinates to draw your Views. If you want to draw a text according to a background position, then may be you should use a **custom View** where the background picture can work as the Background of your custom view and then you can place the text at the exact location.
Another idea would be to use a **9 patch drawable** which is not stretchable (Background uses 9 patch drawable which stretches on changing the size of the view). However you have to supply different drawable for different screen densities then. I'd choose the first option, as it's easier.
PS: Tell me in comment, if you find any difficulty on applying any of the option.